# ionic2: How to change orientation of a single page landscape in app other pages portrait?

Tags: ionic2, orientation

in my app, there has a page need to show in landscape,others show in portrait,i use [ScreenOrientation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation/) plugin

```
this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
```

has no effect when i run on phone and throw some exception

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): NotSupportedError: screen.orientation.lock() is not available on this device.
```

how can i do? thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.
`this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.screenOrientation.unlock();
      this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
  });`